# Button position middle row on form-inline Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm making a form-inline using Bootstrap 4, but when I use a button, the position of the button is always at the top of the row, I want the button's position to be the same as the input field's position, which is in the middle of the row.

```
<form role="form"  id="form_tambah_kriteria" class="margin-bottom-0">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Tipe Decision Maker</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="ion-ios-contacts"></i></span></div>
                <input type="text" name="tipe_dm[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Tipe Decision Maker">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Owned by:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="owner_dm">
                    <option value="">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The following is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pasca21/pen/MWWbBLa?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple fix is to wrap the button in a `form-group` and prefix it with some invisible text (`&nbsp;` or `<br />`). But it would be dead wrong, just a handy hack, because it would simply hide the underlying problem with your codepen.

The proper fix would be to:

- use [latest stable version](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#css) of Bootstrap  - your pen currently uses `v4.0.0-alpha5` which doesn't contain a lot of bugfixes and, among others, does not contain Bootstrap's flexbox classes)
- wrap the button in a `.form-group.col-md-4`
- use `d-flex align-items-end` classes on the `.form-row`

Working example: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/KKKNxZg

---

Note: until you start using the latest stable version of Bootstrap's CSS, you'll keep running into problems which seemingly don't make any sense, because the version you're using is a pre-release which does not include a lot of what most Bootstrap 4 examples take for granted.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is easy just add `<br>` before the button `Delete` for new line...like this:

`<br> <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You should put the button in the third column grid and use the `<br />` .
you should do it as below:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <br />
  <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</div>
```